# BBC Basic Cipher Help Needed

Tags: encryption, basic

I am doing a school project in which I need to make a "sort of" vigenere cipher in which the user inputs both the keyword and plaintext. However the vigenere assumes a=0 whereas I am to assume a=1 and I have changed this accordingly for my program. However I am required to make my cipher work for both lower and upper case, How could I make this also work for lower case, it may be a stupid question but I'm very confused at this point and I'm new to programming, thanks.

```
  REM Variables
  plaintext$=""
  PRINT "Enter the text you would like to encrypt"
  INPUT plaintext$
  keyword$=""
  PRINT "Enter the keyword you wish to use"
  INPUT keyword$
  encrypted$= FNencrypt(plaintext$, keyword$)


  REM PRINTING OUTPUTS
  PRINT "Key = " keyword$
  PRINT "Plaintext  = " plaintext$
  PRINT "Encrypted = " encrypted$
  PRINT "Decrypted  = " FNdecrypt(encrypted$, keyword$)
  END

  DEF FNencrypt(plain$, keyword$)
  LOCAL i%, offset%, Ascii%, output$
  FOR i% = 1 TO LEN(plain$)
    Ascii% = ASCMID$(plain$, i%)
    IF Ascii% >= 65 IF Ascii% <= 90 THEN
    output$ += CHR$((66 + (Ascii% + ASCMID$(keyword$, offset%+1)) MOD 26))
    ENDIF
    offset% = (offset% + 1) MOD LEN(keyword$)
  NEXT
  = output$

  DEF FNdecrypt(encrypted$, keyword$)
  LOCAL i%, offset%, n%, o$
  FOR i% = 1 TO LEN(encrypted$)
    n% = ASCMID$(encrypted$, i%)
    o$ += CHR$(64 + (n% + 26 - ASCMID$(keyword$, offset%+1)) MOD 26)
    offset% = (offset% + 1) MOD LEN(keyword$)
  NEXT
  = output$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert from upper to lowercase and the Stringlib library contains a function for doing this.

First import stringlib at the top of your program:

```
import @lib$+"stringlib"
```

then convert strings using:

```
plaintext$ = fn_lower(plaintext$)
```